# Automated login and takeing screenshot using selenium+phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm writing a Java servlet using Selenium + PhantomJS to log into Alipay (it's like Chinese version of Paypal). I want to get the authentication code by taking screenshot of the login page. My code is as below:

```
package com.alipay.login.test;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.Constants;

public class alipayGetAuthCodeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public byte[] takeScreenshot() throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = (TakesScreenshot) Constants.driver;
        return takesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }

    public BufferedImage createElementImage(WebElement webElement)
        throws IOException {
        Point location = webElement.getLocation();

        Dimension size = webElement.getSize();
        System.out.println(location + " / " + size);
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(takeScreenshot()));
        /*BufferedImage croppedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(
              location.getX(),
              location.getY(),
              size.getWidth(),
              size.getHeight());*/
        return originalImage; // here I return the full screenshot for testing
    }

    protected void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability("takeScreenshot", true);
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "F:\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe"); 

        Constants.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        Constants.driver.get("https://auth.alipay.com/login/index.htm");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Constants.img = Constants.driver.findElement(By.id("J-checkcode-img")).getAttribute("src");
        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }
        if (!Constants.img.equals("")) {
            BufferedImage captcha = createElementImage(Constants.driver.findElement(By.id("J-checkcode-img")));
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 

            try {  
                ImageIO.write(captcha, "jpeg", response.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my servlet, the screenshot I get is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBxI9.png

However, if I use ChromeDriver instead of PhantomJSDriver, the screenshot would be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgaB4.jpg, which is what the login page should be like.
So the screenshot taken by PhantomJSDriver has wrong color (I have no idea about this), wrong size (seems that I can handle this) and most importantly, no authentication code. I have checked the html source code returned by both drivers and found that the div of auth code in PhantomJS has a class of "ui-form-item fn-hide" while the counterpart has a class of "ui-form-item". Is it because the server of Alipay examines what browser I'm using and returns different pages accordingly?

Also I cannot login with only username and password using PhantomJS so I guess I do need an auth code.

Sorry for this long question and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: i havent used phamtomJS with java, but with Laravel yes, and i just recommend you to check the configuration. In some place, i dont remember the configuration you can set the size of document, the resolution, timeout, and another parameters that normally can be Overrided and setted as user want.  Take a lot of time if you have to read this: http://tejasvijava.blogspot.com/2013/01/screen-capture-using-phantomjs.html

Comment: you must change the ViewPort guide here: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html,      and quality, check this too: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html. Regards